# When you didn't expect someone say something

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

When it seems unlikely to hear something from somebody and that person says something that was not expected, which one of the following sentences would sound more natural:

> - I didn’t expect such things coming out of your mouth.
> - Such things were not expected coming out (of / from) your mouth.

Comment: The first is active voice, the second is passive voice. Generally speaking, active voice is always better: it's more concise, easier to understand and, most importantly, says **who** is doing something.

Comment: Thank you very much @JavaLatte; I would be thankful if you could change it to an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is active voice, the second is [passive voice](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/active-and-passive-voice).

You might use passive voice when you don't know who did something (**I was mugged**) or if you don't want to say (**Your vase got broken**), or it's not important to say (**The surveys were carried out over a three year period**).

In all other circumstances, active voice is better: it's more concise, easier to understand and, most importantly, says who is doing something.

The expression **coming out of your mouth** is fine if what was said is inappropriate or offensive. If what's said is quite proper but not expected from this particular person, **from your lips** might be better.
So, you could say any of these:

> I didn’t expect such things coming out of your mouth.
>   I didn't expect such things from your lips.

Answer (score 1):

There are two interpretations of the question:

1. I expected them to say nothing at all, I expected them to be silent.
2. I did not expect them to say those (types of) words.

The phrase "coming out of *your* mouth" is commonly used in sentences like those in the question when telling off a child for using rude (or profane or vulgar) words. It does not complain about the child talking, it complains about the words used.